# Compare two unsigned char structures and bitfields

Tags: c, memcmp

I have a structure containing unsigned chars and bitfields:

```
struct {
unsigned char byt1    ;
unsigned char var1  :1;
unsigned char byt2    ;
unsigned char var2  :1;
unsigned char var3  :1;
unsigned char var4  :1:

} struct1;
```

I want to compare this struct with itself. I keep two copies of this struct and I want to just check if anything changed compared to first copy of it.

Is it safe to use memcmp() here? The real struct has 50+ members, and they are all unsigned chars or bits.

Comment: It is safe to use `memcmp` on bit-field structures just it it is safe to use `memcmp` on any other type of data (variables, arrays, "normal" structures, allocated statically or dynamically). Just as long as the `length` argument that you pass to `memcmp` does not make it exceed the ranges of either one of the input memory blocks, it should work correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure looks like it might contain lots of padding, and the contents of that memory is unspecified (see e.g. [this old SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10954584/440558), and also [this `memcmp` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcmp)), so no you can't really use `memcmp`.

However, if you initialize the structures with e.g. `memset` then it *should* work. It's technically unspecified but in practice the `memset` should set the padding as well.

So to answer your question: If you always clear the structures using `memset` you should in practice be okay using `memcmp`, but in theory it's undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you I just ended up overloading the == operator and doing it the safe way.